# SFML graphics in C++ hangs/crashes at breakpoint with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt, sfml

Currently I am changing from SDL to SFML and experience some undesired behavior. During a breakpoint, the application always crashes. I can either stop the program or continue, but Eclipse is not responding anymore until I quit the program. There most be some workaround for this...

When I put a breakpoint during creating the graphics, I want to debug the composition of graphics on the display. However, at the breakpoint it stops and the application reports:

"Program is not responding. You may choose to wait a short while for it to continue or force the application to quit entirely"

How to debug with SFML during creating the graphics? (In SDL this was never a problem...)

Comment: It is a bit hard to answer this without posting code. Did you at least try with another debugger?

Comment: I'm converting an entire library... at start I create 8 threads for printers, keyboard events, network, rfid and mysql. Concerning graphics, I create a window, then a black window appears on screen and any breakpoint immediately gives a messagebox with the timeout problem. Since SFML also cannot display Chinese, I put sfml on hold for my company at www.kassaku.nl.